# Items won't link to my css file

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to create an 'about page' with photos of my project group members, with our photos rounded and reduced to 200x200px, with captions under it. This worked at first, but after making changes to other things on this website it suddenly stopped working.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

The problem is in the et-slide-about section, it won't link to my css file.

```css
    figure {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    }

    figure img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    }

    figure figcaption {
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    }
    figure figcaption h {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    color: white;
    }

    figure figcaption p {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <main class="et-main">
    <section class="et-slide" id="tab-intro">
      <h1>INTRODUCTION</h1>
      <h2>Shuffling and dealing made easy.</h2><br>
      <h3>The Shuffl'r is the ultimate solution for a fair game of cards.<br> From shuffling to dealing when you want, this robot eliminates all "you barely shuffled"-excuses.</h3>
    </section>
    <section class="et-slide" id="tab-games">
      <h1>GAMES</h1>
      <h2>Any game of cards.<br>Always fair, almost effortless.</h2><br>
      <h3>Almost no effort during your card game, which will help you remain your pokerface while playing. And because The Shuffl'r deals when you want him to deal, you can play any card game you can imagine, from drinking games to poker.</h3>
    </section>
    <section class="et-slide" id="tab-gallery">
      <h1>GALLERY</h1>
      <h2>Our work in action.</h2>  
    </section>
    <section class="et-slide" id="tab-shop">
      <h1>MERCHANDISE</h1>
      <h2>Get everything you need right here.</h2><br><br><br>
    </section>
    <section class="et-slide" id="tab-about">
      <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
      <h2>The geniuses behind The Shuffl'r.</h2><br>
        <section class="et-slide-about">
            <figure>
              <img src=about/tom.png alt='image missing'/>
              <figcaption><br><h>Tom Rassaerts</h>
                  <br><p>Media Design</p></figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
              <img src=about/hank.png alt='image missing'/>
              <figcaption><br><h>Hank Renders</h>
                  <br><p>Technology</p></figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
              <img src=about/fabian.png alt='image missing'/>
              <figcaption><br><h>Fabian Polak</h>
                  <br><p>Allrounder</p></figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
              <img src=about/julian.png alt='image missing'/>
              <figcaption><br><h>Julian van Riel</h>
                  <br><p>Software Engineering</p></figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
              <img src=about/jordy.png alt='image missing'/>
              <figcaption><br><h>Jordy Reynders</h>
                  <br><p>Business</p></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </section>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: have you inspect your page to see if your classname et-slide-about even exist? or if your css file is running on your page?

Comment: Please show us how you are linking to your CSS.

Comment: So it's just supposed to show images which aren't present and names?  What do you mean by it is not linking?  Is you CSS in the same file as the HTML or is the HTML referencing the CSS externally?

Comment: The css file is correctly linked in the head of my html file, the problem is that the <figure> and <figcaption> aren't linking. (Other styles on the same page are responding to changes in the css file, I just uploaded the part where I have problems)

Comment: For clarification, here is the whole code (html, css and js) in codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqxXxa (only my local images are missing, but those can be replaced by internet pictures)

Comment: The images do appear, but without the css styles, thats my problem (sorry if that wasnt clear, posted the question too fast)

Comment: Based on your codepen, I think it's the missing closing bracket `}` after `@keyframes fadein` just above the `figure` css.

Comment: @wmeade, that was the fault, thank you very much!